# slideshow element/android

Tags: android, slideshow

I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:

I would like to create sort of a slideshow element for my app that when a user swipes their finger of the image, it will take them to the next image. If they click on the image, it will take them to a link. Is this possible with Android? This would have to be updated from a link outside of the project of course. So it would have to be on our main Web site. The code cannot be developed in eclipse, since it will be targeting new events.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) or a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), with some ImageViews with click handlers that launch ACTION_VIEW intents with urls.